# Org-agenda-files replaces directories with explicit filenames

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I have a directory `tasks/` in `org-agenda-files` variable. When i add a file to `org-agenda-files` variable through <kbd>C-c [</kbd> command (`org-agenda-file-to-front`), the directory path is replaced by paths of the files, that are currently in that directory. It is bad, because when i add some files to `tasks/` later on, they will not contribute to my agenda.

Is there some way to avoid this, or i'm stuck with manually adding files and directories to `org-agenda-files`?

This problem is acknowledged at [Org Mode - Organize Your Life In Plain Text!](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#AgendaSetup)

Emacs version: 24.0.50.1
Org-mode version: 7.8.09

Comment: I hope I can fix this issue soon.

Comment: No update.  But please raise this issue on the Org-mode mailing list, I don't come here very often.

Comment: Actually I don't understand the problem: the command adds a file to the list of agenda files, not the entire directory.  Adding the entire directory is not what most users would want.  What I'm missing?

Comment: @bzg, when you're trying to add a file, if there's already a directory in the list, it is replaced by the list of files in it.

Comment: And it appears that the explicit filename list is not complete, there are some .org files not included. I've to re-set `org-agenda-files` manually to get those missing entries in my agenda.

Comment: I arrived at the following solution: `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (setq org-agenda-files (list "~/Notebooks/org"))))`. I guess I am forcing a re-assignment of `org-agenda-files` so the explicit filenames are replaced back by the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a command that just adds a file to org-agenda-files without calling org-agenda-files-to-front, and then rebing that to C-c [.  For example:

```
(defun my-org-agenda-file-to-front ()
  (interactive)
  (setq org-agenda-files (append org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c [") `my-org-agenda-file-to-front)
```